# Нужна помощь в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят, такие дела, нужно при разрешении меньше 992px добавить ссылкам меню определенный класс. Как класс добавить я сам понимаю, помогите дополнить скрипт, чтобы это действие происходило на нужном разрешении.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hamburger').click(function(){
      $('.main-list__link').toggleClass('animated');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ вроде верный дан, только без учета поставленной задачи, так что "продублирую":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hamburger').on('click', function(){
      if($(window).width() <= 992) $('.main-list__link').toggleClass('animated');
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо вам просто огромадное, это как раз то, что мне нужно, сидел пытался переделать под себя скрипт ниже, а тут вы пришли на помощь ) Спасибо еще раз

Comment: Всегда рад помочь )

Answer (score 1):

Но лучше сделать через правило @media

```js
function addMenuClass() 
 if ($(window).width() <= '992' && $(селектор ссылок меню:not(.добавляемый класс))) {
     $(селектор ссылок меню).toggleClass(.добавляемый класс);
 }
}

$(window).on('load resize', addMenuClass);
```